# Using Semaphores does not work when opening file in tmp folder

Tags: c, unix, concurrency, posix, semaphore

So, I'm trying to work with concurrency with multi processes(fork).

I first ran the code in my local folder and the code works fine. However, when I tried setting the file into tmp folder in UNIX, my code does not block with a semaphore. It seems to me that when opening a file from tmp folder, each process will do all the work instead of splitting the work or in some rare case 1 process will do all the work and the other two process somehow never get access to the lock.

Driving me insane, if it works for a local file, then there no reason why it would fail in the tmp folder.

The basic goal is I have a set of children processes from `fork()`, only 1 process take control over the CS which is open file, read value from file, store value, close file, modify value, open file, write value file, close file, and that end the CS. I'm using `POSIX semaphore`.

Is there any reason why tmp/file.txt would have issues with `sem_wait()/sem_post()`. Any pointer would be helpful.

The only different between the two code is:

```
fd = open("Seq.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

vs

```
fd = open("tmp/Seq.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

Do I need to post a bigger code snippet?

Comment: Maybe open is failing to find the `tmp/Seq.txt` file. Do you need to add `/` to the path? Something like this `fd = open("/tmp/Seq.txt", O_RDONLY);`. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: God... dangit. That work. Knew it was something simple. Thank. Odd tho, I would think error checking would catch that.

Comment: @Leruce the open() call did not return a negative value when it failed?

Comment: nope, Skipped it and went into fd != -1 next and wrote anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good for you to know how pathnames are resolved so that you can avoid these type of mistakes in the future.

From the online reference of [Path resolution](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) :

Relevant excerpts:

> If the pathname starts with the '/' character, the starting lookup
>      directory is the root directory of the calling process.  (A process
>      inherits its root directory from its parent.  Usually this will be
>      the root directory of the file hierarchy.
>
> **If the pathname does not start with the '/' character, the starting
>      lookup directory of the resolution process is the current working
>      directory of the process.**
>
> Pathnames starting with a '/' character are called absolute
>      pathnames.  Pathnames not starting with a '/' are called relative
>      pathnames.

You can go through the whole page and it will be quite helpful.

If you want to avoid using the absolute path name because of its length,
you can also consider using [`openat()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/openat.htm) instead of `open()`.